# Room database architecture entity extends error

Tags: android, android-database, android-room, android-architecture-components

While using android Room i'm having the following entity:

```
@Entity
public class Call implements Parcelable {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private long id;
private String filePath;
private long durationInMillis;
private String phoneNumber;
private int isStarred;
private int isIncoming;
private long timestampCreated;
}
```

All works great. But now I want my pojo (Call.class) to extends an Abstract class as following:

```
@Entity
public class Call extends BaseViewTypeData implements Parcelable {
....
....
}
```

And i'm getting the following error:

```
Error:Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can 
consider adding a type converter for it.
Error:Cannot find getter for field.
Error:Cannot find setter for field.
Error:Cannot figure out how to read this field from a cursor.
Error:Cannot find getter for field.
Error:Cannot find setter for field.
```

The parent (BaseViewTypeData.class) is a simple class to handle multiple view types in a recycler views.

```
public abstract class BaseViewTypeData extends BaseObservable {

public static final int VIEW_TYPE_CALL = 0;
public static final int VIEW_TYPE_SETTINGS_HEADER = 1;
public static final int VIEW_TYPE_SETTINGS_TITLE_SUBTITLE = 2;
public static final int VIEW_TYPE_SETTINGS_TITLE_SUBTITLE_SWITCH = 3;
public static final int VIEW_TYPE_SETTINGS_DIVIDER = 4;
public static final int VIEW_TYPE_SETTINGS_TITLE_SWITCH = 5;
public static final int VIEW_TYPE_CALL_LOG_DATA = 6;
public static final int VIEW_TYPE_CHECKBOX_TITLE_SUBTITLE = 7;

@Ignore
public abstract int getViewType();

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The parent (BaseViewTypeData.class) is a simple class to handle multiple view types in a recycler views.

I suspect that your problem is not with `BaseViewTypeData`, but with `BaseObservable`, as Room will not know how to deal with [the `BaseObservable` fields](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/master/extensions/library/src/main/java/android/databinding/BaseObservable.java).

In general, having your entity inherit from classes that you do not control is unlikely to work.